# ffmpeg & ffprobe fail to parse dash/vp9 file while mediainfo can

Tags: ffmpeg, vp9, mpeg-dash

(I attached the file, only 808b, as a base64).

This is supposed to be a valid file, but ffmpeg/ffprobe fail.
I'm using a recent build of ffmpeg, but I also tried with older version.

I'd like to understand if it's a ffmpeg bug.

```
ffprobe version N-112876-ga30adf9f96 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
  configuration: --extra-libs= --extra-ldflags= --extra-ldexeflags= --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-autodetect --prefix=/Users/paul/git/ffmpeg-static-builder/dist/mac/arm64//ffmpeg --enable-version3 --pkg-config=pkg-config --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --enable-neon --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-gpl --enable-openssl --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libopus --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libaom --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libmp3lame --enable-zlib --enable-ffprobe --enable-pic --disable-doc --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-libxml2
  libavutil      58. 32.100 / 58. 32.100
  libavcodec     60. 35.100 / 60. 35.100
  libavformat    60. 18.100 / 60. 18.100
  libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavfilter     9. 14.100 /  9. 14.100
  libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
  libswresample   4. 13.100 /  4. 13.100
  libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
[AVFormatContext @ 0x13be05530] Opening 'bin' for reading
[file @ 0x600002680e70] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Probing mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 score:100 size:808
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'ftyp' parent:'root' sz: 24 8 808
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] ISO: File Type Major Brand: dash
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'moov' parent:'root' sz: 784 32 808
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'mvhd' parent:'moov' sz: 108 8 776
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] time scale = 1000
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'mvex' parent:'moov' sz: 40 116 776
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'trex' parent:'mvex' sz: 32 8 32
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'trak' parent:'moov' sz: 628 156 776
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'tkhd' parent:'trak' sz: 92 8 620
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'mdia' parent:'trak' sz: 528 100 620
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'mdhd' parent:'mdia' sz: 32 8 520
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'hdlr' parent:'mdia' sz: 95 40 520
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] ctype=[0][0][0][0]
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] stype=vide
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'minf' parent:'mdia' sz: 393 135 520
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'dinf' parent:'minf' sz: 36 8 385
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'dref' parent:'dinf' sz: 28 8 28
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'stbl' parent:'minf' sz: 329 44 385
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'stsd' parent:'stbl' sz: 237 8 321
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] size=221 4CC=vp09 codec_type=0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'vpcC' parent:'stsd' sz: 20 8 135
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'colr' parent:'stsd' sz: 19 28 135
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] nclx: pri 9 trc 16 matrix 9 full 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'mdcv' parent:'stsd' sz: 32 47 135
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] type:'SmDm' parent:'stsd' sz: 36 79 135
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x13be05530] error reading header
[AVIOContext @ 0x13be057a0] Statistics: 808 bytes read, 0 seeks
bin: Invalid data found when processing input
```

mediainfo returns this:

```
General
Complete name                            : ./bin
Format                                   : dash
Codec ID                                 : dash (iso6/mp41)
File size                                : 808 Bytes
Encoded date                             : 2023-12-01 02:17:00 UTC
Tagged date                              : 2023-12-01 02:17:00 UTC

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : vp09
HDR format                               : SMPTE ST 2086, HDR10 compatible
Codec ID                                 : vp09
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Color space                              : YUV
Title                                    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 11/30/2023.
Encoded date                             : 2023-12-01 02:17:00 UTC
Tagged date                              : 2023-12-01 02:17:00 UTC
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
Mastering display color primaries        : R: x=0.678000 y=0.322000, G: x=0.245000 y=0.703000, B: x=0.138000 y=0.052000, White point: x=0.312700 y=0.329000
Mastering display luminance              : min: 0.0001 cd/m2, max: 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Content Light Level              : 1100 cd/m2
Maximum Frame-Average Light Level        : 180 cd/m2
```

Here is a base64 of the (very small) file:

```
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
```